# Google Map API only returns one result？

Tags: ios, http, dictionary, google-api

I am using the google maps api to develop an iOS  app. I need to find the nearest gas station on the map. When I call an http request: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%gas%20station&sensor=true, it returns one result. But it is the only one. There should be many results. No matter what keywords I submit, it only returns one result. Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

I opened the URL in a browser and got this response :

{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}

According to Google Maps documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#StatusCodes)

"ZERO_RESULTS" indicates that the geocode was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the geocode was passed a non-existent address or a latlng in a remote location.

Gas station is a vague address. Try entering a valid address with a name of the area or city or the street. And you will get results. e.g. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=250%20King%20St%20SF&sensor=true

You need to use the [Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) to search for places like establishments(restaurants, gas stations,etc)

Comment: thank you.When I do some search on maps.google.com (eg. university) , I get a lot of results. But when I use the link http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=university&sensor=true ,I get nothing.I can't understand why? Does google provide different data source when people use api rather than maps.google.com ??

Comment: No. As far as I have experimented, the data is same. The api link that you are trying is for geocoding. And when you search with the keyword "university" on maps.google.com that is not a geocoding request. It is infact a 'places' request. The Places API http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/ will help you with your "university" keyword request and give you results

Comment: thank you.That does help! I should have read the documents carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when I printed the result to the console, it always was showing only one result. But in a debug mode with a breakpoint there were 5 results.
Please check it out using a debug mode.